# Filler submission to the American Mathematical Monthly

Tags: publications

I have found an interesting (and novel) result that I would like to submit to the American Mathematical Monthly. I am aware of the journal's prestige and I understand that my result likely would not warrant regular publication. I am looking to submit my finding and brief proof as "filler", however, their website does not elucidate much information other than a LaTex template for such submissions.

My question to anyone who is familiar with the filler submission process of the American Mathematical Monthly, what are the technical requirements of such a submission? I understand that they are shorter than typical papers but the tables of contents I see online do not seem to include any for length reference.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not a mathematician and I'm not familiar with AMM, so I don't post this as answer, but you can try to start a dummy submission process to see if there is a field allowing to select the type of submission. Some journals have this, allowing to select between, e.g., _regular paper_, _short communication_, _comment_, _special issue paper_ etc.

Comment: I would think that it is the editor who decides how to incorporate such short papers, not the author. Make a submission and wait for the response.

Comment: Related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/19164/what-happens-if-your-manuscript-is-accepted-as-a-filler

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Monthly's journal page has a section on submissions:

https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/american-mathematical-monthly#Submission

There are no listed requirements for fillers, which probably means that there are no strict requirements, just an item the editors deem appropriate.  My first suggestion is to browse through recent issues and look at other fillers to see if yours will fit in.

Second, the above link says:

> Questions concerning submission of papers can be addressed to the editor [name + email]

So if you have specific, focused questions you can try asking.  Alternatively, you could just submit and wait for the review/editorial process for feedback.

Answer (score 1):

A filler is put in when a regular article leaves some blank space at the bottom of its last page.  So by definition they are less than one page.